# Get 2nd from string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a requirement in SQL where I am getting a string and need to get the top 2nd row.
I am using SQL version 2014
I have a string which I am to spitting using the character '`M'`
string is as follows: `3908K88513K1992K898593M`
if I pass input: `88513` I need to get the output as `898593`
Another example is
string: `24572K12345K10981K19809K`
if the input is `19809` output should be: `12345`

I have tried below code but it is failing at 2nd input example string:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 2 *
    FROM splitfunction((
                SELECT number
                FROM name
                WHERE id = 100709
                ), 'K')
    ) AS T
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Use OFFSET / FETCH FIRST instead of TOP.

Comment: Looking at your 2 examples, the ordering isn't even the same in the two. One returns the value *after* but the other the one *before*. What denotes the direction for the "next" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jarlh mentioned in the comments, instead of using `TOP`, use `OFFSET` and `FETCH`:

```sql
SELECT ss.* --This should be your columns
FROM dbo.contact c
     CROSS APPLY dbo.dba_splitstring(c.structureno,'M') ss
WHERE c.recno = 100719
ORDER BY {????} --Your ORDER BY was missing in your query
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I've also reformulated your query, as all those subqueries weren't necessary.

Comment: That isn't the code I put in my answer, @asdfghjkljhgfdfg ... YOu have a subquer in there. You don't need that. The only thing you need to replace is `{????}`, as you didn't define an order in your original query.

Comment: Yes, you editted it, and malformed it, @asdfghjkljhgfdfg ... The latter doesn't make sense though; this will always give the second row as defined by the `ORDER BY`. For rows which have the values. Sounds like you've not told us the *real* problem here. You should be adding sample data and expected results to the question; but now you have answers that can be quite frowned upon if it changes the question significantly.

Comment: `200006` isn't the 2nd row, @asdfghjkljhgfdfg, it's the first.

Comment: That's a different question, @asdfghjkljhgfdfg ... YOU're moving the goal posts. If you're asking a new qusetion, post a new question. Don't post a question, ask for something, get an answer, and then move the goal posts.